# Django template not showing

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I don't know why but my code doesn't work, I don't know where the problem is. Please help, my `product` doesn't appear on the template although I have saved products in the database

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 ftco-animate">
        <div class="product">
            {% if product.ImgProduct %}
            <a href="#" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ product.ImgProduct.url }}" alt="ColorlibTemplate">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </a>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
                <h3><a href="#">{{ product.product_name }}</a></h3>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="pricing">
                        <p class="price"><span>{{ product.product_price }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-area d-flex px-3">
                    <div class="m-auto d-flex">
                        <a href="#" class="add-to-cart d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-menu"></i></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="buy-now d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mx-1">
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-cart"></i></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="heart d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                            <span><i class="ion-ios-heart"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: One way to debug these type of things might be to simply use the following in your `for` loop: `<p>{{ product.product_name }}</p>`. This reduces the complexity of your template. Do you see the correct list of product names? If you see nothing, then `products` is None or empty and you can go back to your server-side code to see how it populated (or rather failed to populate) the `products` list. If you see the list of products then start to reintroduce more of your template till you discover the problem.

Comment: thank you very much. iv already tried this but I cany even see the product name

Comment: So `products` is empty (it has zero length) or it's not empty (but all the product names are blank)?

Comment: thank you very much again .it was the problem with views.py I was sending the wrong context